# There is no executable code at - line number

Tags: android

Okay this is driving me nuts! Please consider the below code:

```
public class PhoneConfigService extends Activity 
{
    public int CheckAPIVersion()
    {
        int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        return version;
    }

    //Basically I am trying to check if data saver mode if enabled for devices with API level greater than 
    @TargetApi(24)
    public boolean CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp() { //line number 70
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (CheckAPIVersion() < 24) {
            return false;
        } else {
            switch (connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus()) {
                case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED:
                    // Background data usage and push notifications are enabled which will block or limit the usage of this app
                    return true;

                case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_WHITELISTED:
                case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED:
                    // Data Saver is disabled or the app is whitelisted
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//My main class
public class TestChanges extends Activity
{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.test_changes);

           String dataSaverMode = Boolean.toString(inst.CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp());
           TextView tvSummary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary);

           if(dataSaverMode == "true")
           {
              //Do some logic
           }
}
```

But whenever I put a break and stepping into the `CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp()` function, I keep on getting an:

> There is no executable code at PhoneConfigService.java:70

Even after I have added the following to my app's `build.gradle` file:

`debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }`

Still does **not** make a difference. I have checked the build variants and I am running the app in debug mode.

**UPDATE:** Please note that it throws the error **before** it even enters the `CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp()` block. It can't even get to the first brace '`{`' inside the method.

**Update II:** As per @MC Emperor's comment, I removed or rather moved the breakpoint to a point further down within the method and I am getting a different exception now:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
>   Activities before onCreate()

After some reading, I see that it might be caused in my `onCreate()` method in my `TestChanges` class where I am instantiating the `PhoneConfigService` class viz.

`PhoneConfigService inst = new PhoneConfigService();`. How can I get I around this? Apparently I can't use `new` to instantiate the class.

I disabled Instant Run, rebuilt (and cleaned) the project and same result.

Comment: is line 70 inside your case statement, by chance? Why not just have a `return  connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus() == RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED` statement there?

Comment: It throws the error as it tries to enter the function. CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp()

Comment: I don't know, but keep this in mind: 1. `dataSaverMode == "true"` — **never** compare strings like this. Always use the `equals()` method. 2. You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: method names always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @MC Emperor What does code standards have to do with the error at hand? There are several other functions in the `PhoneConfigService` class which I am able to debug and step into without any hassle. And those methods follow the same naming convention which I have used.

Comment: @corn3lius I tried your implementation and I still get the same error. I updated my question

Comment: Also why the double parenthesis in the annotation ? shouldn't it be 
- `@TargetApi(24)`

Comment: @Harold_Finch Not much ... except that it is not only a good habit, it also makes your code better readable. For instance, see how the method names are highlighted as if they were class names.

Comment: What happens if you move the break point?

Comment: @corn3lius I fixed that and I still get that error..

Comment: @MC Emperor Please attempt to reproduce the problem with your coding standards and see if the error will go away.

Comment: Try disabling instant run, do a rebuild and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred to @LabeebPanampullan 's answer posted here: [How can I use getSystemService in a non-activity class (LocationManager)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870667/how-can-i-use-getsystemservice-in-a-non-activity-class-locationmanager)

1. I added a constructor (as shown below) to my `PhoneConfigService` class and removed the `extends Activity` This was the root cause to my problem. I knew that because of @Raghunandan 's answer posted here: [IllegalStateException "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460055/illegalstateexception-system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncrea)

`Context mContext;
    public PhoneConfigService(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }`

2. In my `CheckIfAllowDataSaverModeEnabledForApp()` method I passed `Context` as a parameter and changed this line from: `ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` to: `ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`
3. In my `TestChanges` class, I passed in the context when instantiating the `PhoneConfigService` class to look like this: `PhoneConfigService inst = new PhoneConfigService(TestChanges.this);` and all is working as expected now. Thanks to everyone for their valued input.